# DataRow Filter Expression

Tags: c#

Hi I have a DataSet and it has a table called Header. The Header table has a field called Long Agency Code. There is table called Wage that also has a field called Long Agency Code.  I want to filter the Wage table based on the Long Agency Code available in Header Table. The following code snippet shows below:

```
DataTable dt = DataSet.Tables["Header"];

                    DataRowCollection headerRowCollection = dt.Rows;

                    foreach (DataRow headerRow in headerRowCollection)
                    {
                        FixedOutputter outputter = GetOutputter("Header", streamWriter);
                        MapElementCollection mapElementCollection = MapUtility.GetMapElementCollection(DataMap, "Header", DataMapFormatters);
                        outputter.OutputSingleRow(headerRow, mapElementCollection);
                        string filterExpression = "Long Agency Code == '" + headerRow["Long Agency Code"] + "'";
                        DataRow[] wageRowCollection = DataSet.Tables["Wage"].Select(filterExpression);
```

It blows up at the very last line with the message: "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Agency' operator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround `Long Agency Code` in [square brackets], and use a single `=` rather than `==`.

Here is a decent reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

What source did you use when coming up with `Long Agency Code == '(something)'` ?  (It's wrong!)